# How to configure exclusive consumer with Grails and JMS / ActiveMQ?

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a Grails app that subscribes to a given ActiveMQ topic using the JMS plugin. How can I make the TestService class an exclusive consumer? [Details of exclusive consumer here](http://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer.html)

The use case is that I am running the consumer on AWS EC2 and the ActiveMQ feed has a durability of 5 mins and it takes longer than this to replace the instance if it dies. I can't afford to lose messages and message order must be preserved, hence I wish to use multiple instances, where the first instance to connect will be the one that the broker sends every message, and the others are sat in reserve. In the event of the first instance dying, the AMQ broker will send the messages to one of the other instances.

Also, what criteria are used by JMS to determine when an exclusive consumer has died or gone away?

```
// resources.groovy
beans = {
    jmsConnectionFactory(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory) { 
    brokerURL top://example.com:1234 
    userName = 'user' 
    password = 'password' 
    } 
} 

class TestService { 

static exposes = ["jms"] 
static destination = "SOME_TOPIC_NAME" 
static isTopic = true 

def onMessage(msg) { 
    // handle message 

    // explicitly return null to prevent unwanted replyTo attempt 
    return null 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your example uses topics, that won't work; you want queues:

```
class TestService { 
  static expose = ["jms"] 
  static destination = "MYQUEUE" 
  ...
}
```

Configuring exclusive consumers in ActiveMQ is straightforward:

```
queue = new ActiveMQQueue("MYQUEUE?consumer.exclusive=true");
```

..but may be tricky with the Grails plugin; you can try these:

```
class TestService { 
  static expose = ["jms"] 
  static destination = "MYQUEUE?consumer.exclusive=true" 
  def onMessage(msg){ ...}
}


class TestService { 
  static expose = ["jms"] 
  @Queue(
     name = "MYQUEUE?consumer.exclusive=true" 
  )
  def handleMessage(msg){ ...}
}
```

Regarding your question on how the broker determines if a consumer dies, I'm not sure how it's done exactly in ActiveMQ, but in most JMS implementations, TCP failures trigger an exception on the connection; the peer (the broker in this case) handles the exception and fails over to the next available consumer.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go and report back.  Re expose vs exposes, the documentation says "exposes": http://gpc.github.io/grails-jms/docs/manual/index.html

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't work.  It needs to be a topic, not a queue, here is the error message when I try to do otherwise: "A durable subscription requires a topic (pub-sub domain)".  This is because I want to be able to have an exclusive consumer whose connection is durable.

Comment: My bad on `expose`, you're right (I need to slow down reading documentation :-D). Regarding durability, that feature is applicable to messages, not connections. With queues, unless the broker can deliver messages to the consumer, the message will remain on the queue, period. You said messages expire after 5m, can you increase that? Durable subscriptions are expensive and have serious limitations relevant to your use case, see [this](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html), avoid them if possible.

Comment: No, sadly the JMS ActiveMQ feed is outside our company and there is only a 5 min TTL on the messages.  The purpose of the service is to take the JMS feed and transfer into a RabbitMQ service, which has a much higher TTL.

Comment: Raffian is right, exclusive consumers are only applicable to queues.  If you have two consumers on a topic, they will each get a copy of the message, and that's not what you want.  So use queues with non-durable consumers, since durable consumers only apply to topics (as Raffian said, messages aren't removed from queues even when no consumers are connected, so there's no need for the concept of a durable subscription).